# Como interagir com dados do banco com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, json, aplicação-web

Eu estava querendo montar um gráfico com HTML Canvas usando também o Javascript. Os dados necessários estão no banco MySQL.
Porém, como posso interagir e acessar a esses dados do banco Javascript, uma vez que não é seguro usar essa linguagem para a conexão com o banco?
Seria uma página JSON uma solução adequada?

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma é enviar uma solicitação ajax para sua API, sua API faz a consulta no banco e volta um JSON de resposta. A partir do momento que você está de posse do seu JSON, basta fazer o que quiser com os dados.